# Inline call of jQuery tabs doesn't work

Tags: jquery, magento-2.2.5, tabs, footer

Here's my problem.
I have a **tabs block** which load perfectly when I put this script in **phtml**

```
require([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/ui'
        ],
        function($) {
            $("footer").tabs();
        }
    );
```

But if I use `$("footer").tabs();` in browser console, tabs are not working.
Every other components of **jQuery ui** works fine except this one.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Can you load the whole script in console?

Comment: I get the same result with the whole script. Nothing appends and I get no error.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figure it out.

I think there's a conflict with Magento tabs widget, and tabs doesn't load.

Instead I use

```
require([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/ui'
        ],
        function($) {
            $.ui.tabs({}, "footer");
        }
    );
```

And it's now working fine.

Thx for our replies

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 uses require js to load the dependencies before hand when you use following syntax;

```
require([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/ui'
        ],
        function($) {
            $("footer").tabs();
        }
    );
```

i.e jquery,then jquery/ui and then your script.

But when you use `$("footer").tabs();`  the dependencies are not really monitered or loaded by anyone so it may or may not work depending it has loaded or not.

Comment: In my case, dependencies are loaded. I can use jQuery('anyelement').dialog() and it's working fine.